Time-Dependent Air Flow
I am trying to simulate a system where air flows and is heated by the walls. The flow part is as follow:
\[CapitalOmega] = RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, -1/2}, {10, 1/2}], Rectangle[{10, -5}, {15, 5}]];

pde= FluidFlowPDEComponent[{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y], p[t, x, y]}, t, {x, y}}, Entity["Chemical", "Air"]] // MatrixForm == {0,0,0};

ics = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

bcs={DirichletCondition[ {u[t,x, y] == 1/2, v[t,x, y] == 0}, x == 0], DirichletCondition[{u[t,x, y] == 0, v[t,x, y] == 0}, 0 < x < 15], DirichletCondition[p[t,x, y] == 0, x == 15]};

{uVelocity, vVelocity, pressure} = NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ics}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 20},Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];

I'm getting some this error msg:

Could anyone share some thoughts on this topic?

Try removing ‘//MatrixForm’ from ‘Entity["Chemical", "Air"]] // MatrixForm ==‘

Here is a way to do it:
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, -1/2}, {10, 1/2}], 
   Rectangle[{10, -5}, {15, 5}]];

pde = FluidFlowPDEComponent[{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y], p[t, x, y]}, 
     t, {x, y}}, Entity["Chemical", "Air"]] == {0, 0, 0};

inflowProfile = 0.25*(4 - y^2);
(*Plot[inflowProfile,{y,-1/2,1/2}]*)

bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 
      10^-4*1/2*inflowProfile*If[t <= 1, t, 1], v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 0 < x < 15],
    DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 15]};

ics = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

tEnd = 20; 
Monitor[{uVelocity, vVelocity, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ics}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = 
       Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, monitor]

StreamPlot[{uVelocity[tEnd, x, y], 
  vVelocity[tEnd, x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]


A few comments.

As Craig pointed out you should make the inflow and the boundary and the initial conditions consistent. u=1/2 xt x==0 is not consistent with the no-slip BC at wall and it's not consistent with the initial conditions.

You need to think a bit about the scale of things: Inflow velocity of 1/2 [m/s] is quite a bit, so I scaled it a bit down for the solver to handle that.

You probably should refine the mesh a bit: uVelocity["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"]



Also, have a look at the Laminar Flow Monograph that has many tips and information on how to set things up and post process them. Information about mesh generation can be found in the ElementMesh Generation tutorial.
Concerning the pressure difference driven flow, I'd start with something like this:
bcs = {DirichletCondition[{p[t, x, y] == If[t <= 1, t, 1], 
     v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 0 < x < 15],
    DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 15]};

tEnd = 2;
Monitor[{uVelocity, vVelocity, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ics}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
          "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = 
       Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, monitor]

But you see that I have reduces the tEnd time to 2. This is because the solver has a much, much harder time to find a solution. This may because my pressure difference does not make sense. You'd need to put some thought into that.

Nice! Thanks for the solution!
I have another question: how can I change the bcs condition from an inlet/outlet velocity profile to an inlet/outlet pressure profile?

@ThalesSouzaFreire, did you have a look in the laminar flow monograph? That has a section on BCs.

They only talk about velocity BCs.
The example of Rayleigh–Bénard convection is very close to what I want. There is only one thing that I couldn't find out: the dimension of  p[t,x,y]. I t should be Pa, but when I set to p[t,x,y] = 10⁵ at the inlet, NDSolveValue doesn't converge.

You could try to re-scale the coefficients to something more manageable, perhaps.

The warnings go away by removing the MatrixForm and changing the Method:
pde = FluidFlowPDEComponent[{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y], p[t, x, y]}, 
     t, {x, y}}, Entity["Chemical", "Air"]] == {0, 0, 0};

NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs, ics}, {u, v, 
  p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 20}, Method -> {
   "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}
       }}}]

But this still throws an error at t=0 (NDSolveValue::nderr: Error test failure at t == 0.`; unable to continue.)
This is probably because your initial conditions are not consistent with your boundary conditions:
DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 1/2, v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0]

and
u[0, x, y] == 0

conflict.
It looks like you are using the documentation for FluidFlowPDEComp.  In that example, the BCs and ICs are consistent because the u component at the top ramps up from 0 at t=0 (u[t, x, y] == ramp[t])

I see...
Actually, I want the fluid to flow due to a pressure difference at x = 0 and x = 15. But I don't know how to do this.

Perhaps you want steady state?

No, I need the time-dependent problem. My goal is to obtain the temperature profile after 1 second of air flowing through a pip with wall temperature of 313 K, with initial gas inside at equilibrium, and inlet gas at 297 K. The final system looks like a human respiratory system simplified to cylinders, one for the trachea and another with a moving wall for the lung. The varying pressure will be an effect of the change in volume of the lung.

For now, I just want to get the laminar flow right, setting only the varying pressure in one side of the pipe.
